# CSS & JS not loading properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I got these scripts but they're not loading properly. Can't say for sure what the issue is but the CSS and JS don't look like they're being picked up. Cause the `index.html` isn't being rendered as it should.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing. It's probably something annoyingly small.

I feel like I've referenced the css and js with the script and link tags, but it still doesn't get rendered.

I listed the three scripts below. Any ideas please?

`index.html`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class='moon'>
  <div class='crater1'></div>
  <div class='crater2'></div>
  <div class='crater3'></div>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="sea"></div>
<div id="beach"></div>
<img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/2k0mtrxc2dqurmh/jumping.png" alt="jumping-people" id="people" />
<!--<img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zoftkmdxyyqr8ce/belair.png" alt="jumping-people" id="car" />-->

<div id="merrywrap" class="merrywrap">
  <div class="giftbox">
    <div class="cover">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="row"> 
      <span>H</span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>p</span>
      <span>p</span>
      <span>y</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 
      <span>B</span>
      <span>i</span>
      <span>r</span>
      <span>r</span>
      <span>t</span>
      <span>h</span>
      <span>d</span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>y</span>

    </div>
    <div class="row"> 
      <span>D</span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>v</span>
      <span>e</span>
      <!-- <span>t</span>
      <span>h</span>
      <span>e</span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>r</span>
      <span>t</span> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="style.js"></script>

<div id="video">
<!--<iframe width="255" height="155" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MrXBATtOtFY?controls=0&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
</div>
```

`style.css`

```
/* Kaushan+Script, oregano, sail */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script');

html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script','Sail', cursive;
}

body {
    background: #e74;
    overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, #190e14 ,#0d0d4b 30%, #c76075 80%, #e9b64b 95% );
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at center bottom, #e9b64b ,#c76075 15%, #0d0d4b 75%, #190e14 90%);
}

div#beach,
canvas#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div#beach {
  background-image: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/oe0oce2udq44bj5/beachsil2.png);
  /* background-size: cover; */
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-size: 1700px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div#video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 243px;
  bottom: 200px;
}

div#video iframe {
  width: 255px;
  height: 155px;
}

#people {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 65px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 140px;
}

#car {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 46px;
  left: 180px;
  width: 230px;
}

div#sea {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at center top, #23485a, #0d0246);
}

.merrywrap{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #d44;
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
}
.giftbox{
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  bottom: 40px;
  z-index:10;
  &>div{
    background: #34495e;
    position: absolute;
    &:after,&:before{
      position: absolute;
      content:"";
      top: 0;
    }
  }
  &:after{
    position: absolute;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    content:"Click Me!";
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    transform:rotate(-20deg);
    transform-origin:0 0;
  }
  .cover{
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:25%;
    z-index:2;
    &:before{
      position: absolute;
      height:100%;
      left: 50%;
      width:50px;  transform:translateX(-50%);
      background:#fdc56d;
    }
    &>div{
      position: absolute;
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      left:50%;
      top:-50px; transform:translateX(-50%);
      &:before,&:after{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        content:"";
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 15px #fdc56d;
        border-radius:30px;
        transform-origin:50% 100%;
      }
      &:before{
        transform:translateX(-45%) skewY(40deg);
      }
      &:after{   transform:translateX(45%) skewY(-40deg);
      }
    }
  }
  .box{
    right:5%;
    left:5%;
    height:80%;
    bottom: 0;
    &:before{ 
      width:50px;
      height:100%;
      left:50%;
      transform:translateX(-50%);
      background:#fdc56d;
    }
    &:after{
      width:100%;
      height:30px;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
  }
}
.icons{
  position:absolute;
  left: 10px;
  /*top:50%;
  width: 100%;*/
  height: auto; 
  transform:translateY(10px) rotate(-20deg); 
  .row{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center; 
    span{ 
      color: #e5e5e5;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(96, 125, 139, 0.4);
      font-size: 50px;   
      display: inline-block;
      opacity:0;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in, opacity 0.7s;
    }
  } 
}
.step-1{
  .giftbox{
    animation:wobble 0.5s linear infinite forwards;
  }
  .cover{
     animation:wobble 0.5s linear infinite  0.1s forwards;
  }
  .icons .row span{
    opacity:1;
  }
}
.step-2 .giftbox:after{
  opacity:0;
}
.step-3 .giftbox,
.step-4 .giftbox{
    opacity: 0;
  z-index:1;
  &:after{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
.step-2{
  .giftbox{
    .cover{
      animation:flyUp 0.4s ease-in forwards;
    }
    .box{
      animation:flyDown 0.2s ease-in 0.05s forwards;
    }
  }
}
@keyframes wobble{
  25%{
    transform:rotate(4deg);
  }
  75%{
    transform:rotate(-2deg);
  }
}
@keyframes flyUp{
  75%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    transform:translateY(-1000px) rotate(20deg);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes flyDown{
  75%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    transform:translateY(100%);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
.step-1 .icons .row span{
  opacity:0;
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:first-child { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(600%);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(2) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(500%);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(3) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(400%);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(4) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(300%);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(5) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(200%);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(6) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(100%);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(7) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(0);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(8) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(-100%);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(9) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(-200%);
}
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(10) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(-300%);
}  
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(11) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(-400%);
} 
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(12) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(-500%);
} 
.step-1 .icons .row span:nth-child(13) { 
        transform: translateY(700%) translateX(-600%);
} 
.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(9) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.45s;
    transition-delay: 0.45s;
}
.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(10) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(11) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.55s;
    transition-delay: 0.55s;
}
.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(12) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
.step-2 .icons .row span:nth-child(13) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.65s;
    transition-delay: 0.65s;
}
.step-2 .icons span,.step-3 .icons span,.step-4 .icons span {
    opacity: 1; 
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.000, 0.200, 0.910);
}
.step-4 .icons .row span,.step-3 .icons .row span { 
    /*animation: wobble 0.6s linear infinite forwards;*/
  color: #c6e2ff;
    animation: neon .08s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.step-4 .icons .row span:nth-child(even),.step-3 .icons .row span:nth-child(even) { 
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
}

@keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow:
    0 0 6px rgba(202,228,225,0.92),
    0 0 30px rgba(202,228,225,0.34),
    0 0 12px rgba(30,132,242,0.52),
    0 0 21px rgba(30,132,242,0.92),
    0 0 34px rgba(30,132,242,0.78),
    0 0 54px rgba(30,132,242,0.92);
  }
  to {
    text-shadow:
    0 0 6px rgba(202,228,225,0.98),
    0 0 30px rgba(202,228,225,0.42),
    0 0 12px rgba(30,132,242,0.58),
    0 0 22px rgba(30,132,242,0.84),
    0 0 38px rgba(30,132,242,0.88),
    0 0 60px rgba(30,132,242,1);
  }
}

.moon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  box-shadow: inset 20px -10px 0 0 #b9b9b9;
}
.moon .crater1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #bbb;
  box-shadow: inset -3px 1.5px 0 0 #aaa;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
.moon .crater2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #bbb;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0.5px 0 0 #aaa;
  top: 45px;
  right: 50px;
}
.moon .crater3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #bbb;
  box-shadow: inset -1.5px 0.75px 0 0 #aaa;
  top: 60px;
  right: 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .icons { left: 30px; }
  .icons .row span { font-size: 56px; }
  #people {
    left: 80px;
    bottom: 70px;
    width: 160px;
  }
  div#beach {
    background-size: 2000px;
  }
  div#video {
    right: 290px;
    bottom: 235px;
  }
  div#video iframe {
    width: 295px;
    height: 185px;
  }
  .moon {
    right: 230px;
  }
}
```

`script.js`

```
window.requestAnimFrame = ( function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function( callback ) {
                    window.setTimeout( callback, 1000 / 60 );
                };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' ),
        ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' ),
        // full screen dimensions
        cw = window.innerWidth,
        ch = window.innerHeight,
        // firework collection
        fireworks = [],
        // particle collection
        particles = [],
        
        hue = 120,
        
        limiterTotal = 5,
        limiterTick = 0,
        
        timerTotal = 80,
        timerTick = 0,
        mousedown = false,
        
        mx,
        
        my;
        
canvas.width = cw;
canvas.height = ch;

function random( min, max ) {
    return Math.random() * ( max - min ) + min;
}

// calculate the distance between two points
function calculateDistance( p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y ) {
    var xDistance = p1x - p2x,
            yDistance = p1y - p2y;
    return Math.sqrt( Math.pow( xDistance, 2 ) + Math.pow( yDistance, 2 ) );
}

// create firework
function Firework( sx, sy, tx, ty ) {
    // actual coordinates
    this.x = sx;
    this.y = sy;
    // starting coordinates
    this.sx = sx;
    this.sy = sy;
    // target coordinates
    this.tx = tx;
    this.ty = ty;
    // distance from starting point to target
    this.distanceToTarget = calculateDistance( sx, sy, tx, ty );
    this.distanceTraveled = 0;
    
    this.coordinates = [];
    this.coordinateCount = 3;
    // populate initial coordinate collection with the current coordinates
    while( this.coordinateCount-- ) {
        this.coordinates.push( [ this.x, this.y ] );
    }
    this.angle = Math.atan2( ty - sy, tx - sx );
    this.speed = 2;
    this.acceleration = 1.05;
    this.brightness = random( 50, 70 );
    // circle target indicator radius
    this.targetRadius = 1;
}

// update firework
Firework.prototype.update = function( index ) {
    // remove last item in coordinates array
    this.coordinates.pop();
    // add current coordinates to the start of the array
    this.coordinates.unshift( [ this.x, this.y ] );
    
    // cycle the circle target indicator radius
    if( this.targetRadius < 8 ) {
        this.targetRadius += 0.3;
    } else {
        this.targetRadius = 1;
    }
    
    // speed up the firework
    this.speed *= this.acceleration;
    
    // get the current velocities based on angle and speed
    var vx = Math.cos( this.angle ) * this.speed,
            vy = Math.sin( this.angle ) * this.speed;
    // how far will the firework have traveled with velocities applied?
    this.distanceTraveled = calculateDistance( this.sx, this.sy, this.x + vx, this.y + vy );
    
    // if the distance traveled, including velocities, is greater than the initial distance to the target, then the target has been reached
    if( this.distanceTraveled >= this.distanceToTarget ) {
        createParticles( this.tx, this.ty );
        // remove the firework, use the index passed into the update function to determine which to remove
        fireworks.splice( index, 1 );
    } else {
        // target not reached, keep traveling
        this.x += vx;
        this.y += vy;
    }
}

// draw firework
Firework.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    // move to the last tracked coordinate in the set, then draw a line to the current x and y
    ctx.moveTo( this.coordinates[ this.coordinates.length - 1][ 0 ], this.coordinates[ this.coordinates.length - 1][ 1 ] );
    ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y );
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(' + hue + ', 100%, ' + this.brightness + '%)';
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    // draw the target for this firework with a pulsing circle
    ctx.arc( this.tx, this.ty, this.targetRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
    ctx.stroke();
}

// create particle
function Particle( x, y ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // track the past coordinates of each particle to create a trail effect, increase the coordinate count to create more prominent trails
    this.coordinates = [];
    this.coordinateCount = 5;
    while( this.coordinateCount-- ) {
        this.coordinates.push( [ this.x, this.y ] );
    }
    // set a random angle in all possible directions, in radians
    this.angle = random( 0, Math.PI * 2 );
    this.speed = random( 1, 10 );
    // friction will slow the particle down
    this.friction = 0.95;
    // gravity will be applied and pull the particle down
    this.gravity = 1;
    // set the hue to a random number +-20 of the overall hue variable
    this.hue = random( hue - 20, hue + 20 );
    this.brightness = random( 50, 80 );
    this.alpha = 1;
    // set how fast the particle fades out
    this.decay = random( 0.015, 0.03 );
}

// update particle
Particle.prototype.update = function( index ) {
    // remove last item in coordinates array
    this.coordinates.pop();
    // add current coordinates to the start of the array
    this.coordinates.unshift( [ this.x, this.y ] );
    // slow down the particle
    this.speed *= this.friction;
    // apply velocity
    this.x += Math.cos( this.angle ) * this.speed;
    this.y += Math.sin( this.angle ) * this.speed + this.gravity;
    // fade out the particle
    this.alpha -= this.decay;
    
    // remove the particle once the alpha is low enough, based on the passed in index
    if( this.alpha <= this.decay ) {
        particles.splice( index, 1 );
    }
}

// draw particle
Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx. beginPath();
    // move to the last tracked coordinates in the set, then draw a line to the current x and y
    ctx.moveTo( this.coordinates[ this.coordinates.length - 1 ][ 0 ], this.coordinates[ this.coordinates.length - 1 ][ 1 ] );
    ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y );
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + this.hue + ', 100%, ' + this.brightness + '%, ' + this.alpha + ')';
    ctx.stroke();
}

// create particle group/explosion
function createParticles( x, y ) {
    // increase the particle count for a bigger explosion, beware of the canvas performance hit with the increased particles though
    var particleCount = 30;
    while( particleCount-- ) {
        particles.push( new Particle( x, y ) );
    }
}

// main demo loop
function loop() {
    // this function will run endlessly with requestAnimationFrame
    requestAnimFrame( loop );
    
    // increase the hue to get different colored fireworks over time
    hue += 0.5;
    
    // normally, clearRect() would be used to clear the canvas
    // we want to create a trailing effect though
    // setting the composite operation to destination-out will allow us to clear the canvas at a specific opacity, rather than wiping it entirely
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    // decrease the alpha property to create more prominent trails
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, cw, ch );
    // change the composite operation back to our main mode
    // lighter creates bright highlight points as the fireworks and particles overlap each other
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    
    // loop over each firework, draw it, update it
    var i = fireworks.length;
    while( i-- ) {
        fireworks[ i ].draw();
        fireworks[ i ].update( i );
    }
    
    // loop over each particle, draw it, update it
    var i = particles.length;
    while( i-- ) {
        particles[ i ].draw();
        particles[ i ].update( i );
    }
    
    // launch fireworks automatically to random coordinates, when the mouse isn't down
    if( timerTick >= timerTotal ) {
        if( !mousedown ) {
            // start the firework at the bottom middle of the screen, then set the random target coordinates, the random y coordinates will be set within the range of the top half of the screen
            fireworks.push( new Firework( cw / 2, ch, random( 0, cw ), random( 0, ch / 2 ) ) );
            timerTick = 0;
        }
    } else {
        timerTick++;
    }
    
    // limit the rate at which fireworks get launched when mouse is down
    if( limiterTick >= limiterTotal ) {
        if( mousedown ) {
            // start the firework at the bottom middle of the screen, then set the current mouse coordinates as the target
            fireworks.push( new Firework( cw / 2, ch, mx, my ) );
            limiterTick = 0;
        }
    } else {
        limiterTick++;
    }
}

window.onload=function(){
  var merrywrap=document.getElementById("merrywrap");
  var box=merrywrap.getElementsByClassName("giftbox")[0];
  var step=1;
  var stepMinutes=[2000,2000,1000,1000];
  function init(){
          box.addEventListener("click",openBox,false);
  }
  function stepClass(step){
    merrywrap.className='merrywrap';
    merrywrap.className='merrywrap step-'+step;
  }
  function openBox(){
    if(step===1){
      box.removeEventListener("click",openBox,false); 
    }  
    stepClass(step); 
    if(step===3){ 
    } 
    if(step===4){
        reveal();
       return;
    }     
    setTimeout(openBox,stepMinutes[step-1]);
    step++;  
  }
   
  init();
 
}

function reveal() {
  document.querySelector('.merrywrap').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  
  loop();
  
  var w, h;
  if(window.innerWidth >= 1000) {
    w = 295; h = 185;
  }
  else {
    w = 255; h = 155;
  }
  
  var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/MrXBATtOtFY?controls=0&loop=1&autoplay=1");
        //ifrm.style.width = `${w}px`;
        //ifrm.style.height = `${h}px`;
        ifrm.style.border = 'none';
        document.querySelector('#video').appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

Comment: _"I dumped the three scripts below"_ - That's not how SO works... [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Are there legitimate “fix my code” questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions/253788#253788)

Comment: Apologies. I couldn't post the question initially as I kept getting prompted to include more words and less code. So I just kept adding more words. Hence the off wording in end.

Comment: Delete everything from your script.js and put at the top, on one line by itself `alert("script.js")` then re-run your page.  Do you get the alert?  No, then it's a problem with your include in your page, yes then that part is ok.

Comment: Check your browser console *and* network tab for any errors - you'll probably be getting a 404 on `style.js` as you've stated it's called `script.js` but your `<script src=style.js` has style.js

Comment: Whenever there's any problem with css/js that you can't find what the problem is, alwys start with the minimal code to get the "framework" up and running - a simple html page with your css `<link` and script `<script src=` and maybe some text to apply the css to.  A simple `alert` in the script and something like `body { color: red }` in the css.  9/10 (anecdotal) they'll be something minor (like script.js/style.js) or the wrong path and this will get you there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have another look.

Comment: start with just a minimal working index page and then add some parts step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing

```
<script src="style.js"></script>
```

I assume you ment to reference the "script.js" file..

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

I also suggest to add the async keyword to the tag for better performence:
https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/

Comment: This should be classified as a typo and close-voted as such once confirmed by OP (via comments) that it fixes all their issues.  It's quite likely it was a mis-type into the question rather than a problem in their original code.

Comment: Good point. Thanks